# javascript: window.location doesn't open a new window on all browsers

Tags: javascript, window.location

I have a strange problem. On some browsers (like chrome) the code below opens a new window. So it works as expected. On other browsers (like firefox)  It just shows the alert box So it don't open the requested window.
Any suggestion for a code that works on all browsers?

```
if(TestVar == "1810" ) 
            {
                alert ("test  " + TestVar + "! ");
                window.location.href="http://astyle.home.xs4all.nl/beautyfarm2003/wellnessbon_321442.html";
            }

if(TestVar == "1920" ) 
            {
                alert ("Test " + TestVar + "! "); 
                window.location="http://astyle.home.xs4all.nl/beautyfarm2003/wellnessbon_1925485.html";
            }  // Vriendinnendag
```

Comment: open a new window, aka, you mean it does not navigate to the new page?  You make it sound like you are using window.open(), but you are not.

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to work just fine in Chrome, Internet Explorer 9/10, and Firefox for me.

Try the following: http://jsbin.com/uluziz/edit#javascript,html

If you want to open a new window, you wouldn't be changing `window.location`. That just changing location your *current* window is at. Use `window.open()` instead to  open a new window to a new location:

```
var myWin = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com','SO','width=640,height=480');

setTimeout(function(){
  myWin.close();
}, 2000);
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ekoluk/3/edit